# Query gives me duplicates at times

Tags: sql

I have this issue with my search option.
My problem is, it gives me duplicates. And it can't be, because if I search by ID it gives me two rows, and the ID is unique.
This is the query I use:

```
SELECT forma.*, SMS_MONTIME.IDTICKET, SMS_MONTIME.MBYLLUR,SMS_MONTIME.time_added
FROM forma 
LEFT JOIN SMS_MONTIME ON forma.ID = SMS_MONTIME.IDTICKET where forma.$kategoria LIKE '%$search%' ORDER BY forma.ID
```

What can I use in order to avoid duplicates? Maybe not left join.

Comment: Do you have multiple records in your SMS_MONTIME table associated with that ID?

Comment: How did i not think about that....

Comment: sometimes it just takes a different set of eyes.

Comment: i am also facing the same issue my partitioned cache give me duplicate records even its have not duplcicate rows have you find any answer @pyetjegoo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This happens when you have more that one row in `SMS_MONTIME` table with `IDTICKET` equal to a single `forma.ID`. For example if you have only one row in `forma` table with `ID` equal to `10`, you may have two rows in `SMS_MONTIME` with `IDTICKET` equal to `10`. Then you get two rows in the result, with duplicate information from `forma` table and distinct information from `SMS_MONTIME` table.

You cannot avoid this unless you rethink the result you want. What should happen to distict information of the `SMS_MONTIME` table? You may need to extract required information with separate queries, or you may process the result (with duplicates) to extract the reqired information.

Comment: This answer tells you the reason you got duplicates.  With regards to avoiding them, it might not be possible, even if you use "select distinct" as suggested by @sansix.  It depends on the data you want to retrieve, and you are supposed to know that before you write your query.

Answer (score 0):

have you tried with `DISTINCT`

```
SELECT DISTINCT column_name(s)
FROM table_name
Where <conidition>
```

check [this link](http://www.w3resource.com/sql/select-statement/queries-with-distinct-multiple-columns.php)

Comment: How can i implement this in my query above please...?

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in my comment, if you have multiple records in your SMS_MONTIME table, you're going to receive duplicates.  If you only want to receive a single record, you can get the MAX(time_added) and just show that record.  Here is an example:

```
SELECT forma.*, SMS_MONTIME.IDTICKET, SMS_MONTIME.MBYLLUR,SMS_MONTIME.time_added
FROM forma 
    LEFT JOIN (
        SELECT IDTICKET, MAX(time_added) max_time_added
        FROM SMS_MONTIME 
        GROUP BY SMS_MONTIME.IDTICKET
    ) SMS_MONTIME_MAX ON forma.ID = SMS_MONTIME_MAX.IDTICKET 
    LEFT JOIN SMS_MONTIME ON 
        forma.ID = SMS_MONTIME.IDTICKET AND SMS_MONTIME.time_added AND SMS_MONTIME_MAX.max_time_added
WHERE forma.$kategoria LIKE '%$search%' 
ORDER BY forma.ID
```

Hope this helps.